# How to list all user principals from realm in an application server (glassfish)?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have a Java EE 6 application, where every user has its own jpa entity. Since I'd like to create these entities when the application is deployed to the server i need a way to list all principals or at least the names. Is there a standard way to receive the user names in all application server or if not is there a way for glassfish only?

My backup plan is to create the the entitiy on the first login of a user but I'd really prefer to do it at earlier so an administrator can modify the user entity even before the user logs in for the first time.

Thanks 
Raffael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. A realm or (Jaspic) authentication module can connect to any authentication provider like an LDAP server or OAuth provider. Especially with social networks like Google or Facebook you can't expect to retrieve a listing of all available users,

Because of this universal connectivity such a method cannot be made available in the standard API.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about realms like OAuth. I just thought about databses, ldap or file, but I see that it's hardly possible since they all use the same api as others. But a list of all Facebook users would be fun :-)